# C++ Using a string variable to call and give names to other stuff

Tags: c++, variables

How can I give a name to a new variable or object using a string variable?

For example: After I compile the program, I enter the text "`a_name`", press [Enter] and then a vaiable or object with the name "a_name" gets declared. Another example: I enter the text "`a_name`", press [Enter] and then the variable called "a_name" shows it's value.

Are there any special Libraries for this, that have to be downloaded? Or are there ones that are included in the compilers files? If there are libraries that have to be downloaded, which are the easiest to understand and use? I'm using Visual C++, but with the Libraries Iostream, Math, String, e.t.c. copied from the DevC++ compiler.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7396/

Comment: you enter the text "a_name" where, exactly?  Are you actually trying to _write_ some sort of interpreter?

Comment: @MithunSasidharan: I think that's not what he's asking.

Answer (score 6):

You can't add "variables" to a program once it has been compiled.  You
can get more or less the same effect, however, by using `std::map`, with
a string as the key type.

You will, of course, have to decide what type the new variable should
have, so you know what type to map it to.  If there may be more than one type, something like `boost::variant` might be useful.  (Note that unlike the set of names, the set of possible types must be completely defined at compile-time.)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can't. Variable names are set up on compile time and not on run time. C++ is not interpreted (like Perl, Python or JavaScript) thus it can't evaluate expressions on run time. C++ is ol' school.

I suggest you using arrays or C++ list/map classes to try to simulate this behavior.

Comment: Yes, c++ does not support named variables/arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare variables like that, what you may do however is use a `map` where the key of the map is the name of the variable you would like to refer to, and the value in the map having that key, is the value of the variable.

`std::map<std::string, std::string> variables;`

Obviously the value could be any type, and not just a string like I have used here, you can use `double`, `int`, `bool` or whatever suits your need, or if you need different types you might even use [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) as James Kanze suggested, or any other similar class.

Read more about maps here: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html and here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

You can use any kind of map, but a map using a sort of hashing to store the key might be your best bet. STL hash_map: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you are trying to do is include an interpreted language into your C++ program.

There are many languages that support being embedded into a C++ program Lua, JavaScript, Python to mention a few.

Comment: +1, if you want scripting on top of your program, it is probably easier and better to provide an existing language from a library than write your own.